# Using third-party dependencies in polymer (pikadate)

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm creating a polymer datepicker using [pikaday](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday). Sadly it seems like I got something wrong.

I'd like to import `pikaday.js` and `pikaday.css` *the right way*.

At first I had a simple script-tag below my closing `dom-module`-tag, like

```
</dom-module>
<script src="../../pikaday/pikaday.js"></script>
<script>
  Polymer({
    //....
```

This way, the datepicker was created as expected. But after reading this [SO-Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22135095/polymer-element-with-javascript-dependencies) I was under the impression I was supposed to import the js-file like this:

```
 <link rel="import" href="../../paper-input/paper-input-behavior.html">
 <link rel="import" href="../../paper-input/paper-input-error.html">
 <link rel="import" href="../../pikaday/pikaday.js">
 //more imports....
```

But after "fixing" my import, the file `pikaday.js` seems not to be visible from inside my component:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Pikaday is not defined
```

Furthermore I'm confused about using external css. After reading [this guide](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling#style-modules) it seems like I was supposed to copy & paste the contents of the provided css-file into a `my-datepicker-style.html` and to import it into my template like this:

```
<dom-module id="my-datepicker">
  <template>
    <style include="my-datepicker-style"></style>
    <style>
      :host {
        //more css
```

I'm confused about the need to copy & paste existing code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Until ES6 imports are more common, you need some kind of workaround for referencing dependencies.

The problem with `<script>` tag is that when it appears multiple times, it will be processed multiple times. This is not true for `<link rel="import">`. Same href will be processed only once.

You cannot, however, import javascript directly. The trick is to create `pikaday-import.html` file with the script reference

```
<script src="../../pikaday/pikaday.js"></script>
```

You then import that in your element's html

```
<link rel="import" href="pikaday-import.html" />
<dom-module id="my-datepicker"></dom-module>
```

This is the technique for example the `<marked-element>` [uses](https://github.com/PolymerElements/marked-element/blob/master/marked-import.html).

This way instances of `<my-datepicker>` load pickaday only once. Unfortunately, if there are other components which reference it, you could end up loading the dependency multiple times.

Comment: Works like a charme. Thanks a lot.